# JavaFX MenuBar items flicker when moving pointer on it

Tags: linux, javafx-2

I have inherited a JavaFX project and have a problem when running it on linux. When dropping down a MenuBar menu and hovering over items with my pointer the selection flicker and items get selected only at certain spots of the area of the item. Where these spots are and the distribution of select vs. non-select spots are seemingly random, changing when closing the menu and opening it again. When clicking an item when it isn't highlighted as hovered nothing happens.

What could be the problem and where would I even start looking. I can't find anything that has been customized when it comes to the dropdown menus and they work flawlessly on macosx.

Comment: Could you provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), please? I would like to test this locally.

Comment: I suggest to create a small menubar demo project with the same properties of original project and examine the mentioned behavior there, to be sure if it is platform and/or hardware dependent problem. If not the same behavior, check for mouse event handlers of the menuitem itself or its graphic if exists. Use "-fx-border-color" styles of menubar, menuitem, menuitem's graphic to visually determine the bounds of them and hence the mouse hovering borders.

Comment: If you think you've found a bug, please file an issue here: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: I will have to look in to creating a SSCCE later (have to do it off the clock since linux isn't a prioritized platform). But just to verify that it isn't something off with this project I can mention that I have the exact same problem with the JavaFX Scene Builder, it's just slightly less, guessing it can be that the project I'm working on is a lot more heavily styled.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I thought the problem would be solved when javafx scene builder for linux was officially released but i am still facing the same problem.

Comment: No, I haven't found any solution to this.

Comment: still no Solution? i have the same Problem on SuseLinux 12.3. i face it in my Application and in the fx Scene Builder too.

Comment: See this workaround [http://pathlesspath.blogspot.com/2010/06/how-to-get-java-fx-menus-to-work-on.html], which is a response to RT-8819 [https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-8819].  Notice the resolution is "Won't Fix".